# How is it possible to know whether a service is a user service or a system service?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd

Is it possible to query a service and know for example whether it was initiated from the `lib/systemd/system` or from `/.config/systemd/user/`?

I'm in the middle of writing a `systemd` service, and currently I have put it in the `lib/systemd/system` it runs as root, but I also want to make it work for each user as well.

I have some checks in my service, that needs to know, if it has root access or not. That's why I'm trying to figure out if I can get such information concerning a service.

I'm using Ubuntu, but I'd like to know if the solution is applicable to other distros that use `systemd` as well.

Comment: You can use `ps aux` to get the owning user of a process. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Rika, you can use `systemctl cat name.service` and the first line in #comment will tell you where it's located.

Comment: @– ctrl-alt-delor thanks a lot. but no.
@ValentinBajrami: Thanks a lot thats really helpful much better than systemctl status that I have been using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your main service runs as root, you can have a very simple test like so:

```
if(getuid() == 0)
{
    ...act as root...
}
else
{
    ...act as user...
}
```

You may also be interested by the `seteuid()` function. That allows you to change between users, which is really possible only if you can become root and then switch to any other user. You can become root if the executable has the `s` flag, which for a service is really not recommended (and by default systemd prevents such changes from happening).

Finally, systemd lets you run a multi-user service as a user other than root. That means its identifier would not be 0. If you are using such a feature, then you need to determine the id first.

```
struct passwd * p = getpwnam("my-global-service-user-name");
if(getuid() == p->pw_uid)
...
```

The user name could be `"root"` and the function will return the `/etc/passwd` entry for the root user which has `uid` set to 0.